# What does the word "they" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He looks back at her, refusing to shrink from her very direct gaze.
>   “David Paley,” he says, waiting for it. She’s a journalist, after all.
>   **They** have no compunction about anything. He knows his weekend is about
>   to be ruined.

What does the word "they" refer to? Does it generally refer to journalists? Or refers to Guen  and Riley?

The fuller text is:

> “You’re a defense attorney,” **Gwen** says, when the silence verges on
>   becoming awkward. “Yes,” he says. Oddly, he can’t think of anything
>   else to say. He finds that he’s tongue-tied. He’s not usually, but he
>   can feel her friend[Riley] oozing barely veiled hostility, and it’s
>   disconcerting. “That must be interesting,” Gwen says gamely. “And
>   challenging. Although probably exhausting too.” “Yes,” he
>   agrees[...]“**Riley** and I were at journalism school together. She’s with
>   the New York Times.” He flicks a nervous glance at Riley, inwardly
>   dismayed. “But I never actually worked as a journalist,” Gwen
>   confides. “Is that right,” David says, his mind drifting from the
>   conversation. “What do you do instead?” “I work in public relations
>   for a small firm in New York City.” “And do you enjoy it?” But he is
>   already thinking of an exit strategy. “For the most part,” she says.
>   “It can be exciting, but it can also be a grind. Like a lot of jobs,
>   it sounds more glamorous than it is.” They talk for a while, about
>   nothing much. When they are about to start on coffee and
>   dessert—English trifle and chocolate brownies have appeared on the
>   long buffet table—Riley, slurring her words slightly, turns and looks
>   directly at him and says, “I’ve been trying to place you—what did you
>   say your name was again?” He looks back at her, refusing to shrink
>   from her very direct gaze. “David Paley,” he says, waiting for it.
>   She’s a journalist, after all. **They have no compunction about
>   anything.** He knows his weekend is about to be ruined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They is referring to journalists, you are correct.  I have two points that I used to

The first point is based on the previous sentence.  It references journalists, and then the very next pronoun, "they", is most likely referring to the journalists.

The second point follows the first, and is based on the [definition of compunction](https://www.google.com/search?q=compunction&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS796US796&oq=compunction&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61j0l2.1359j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  The definition is *"a feeling of guilt or moral scruple that prevents or follows the doing of something bad"*, and a trope about journalists is that they (slight irony with my use of they here) will do anything to get a story, even morally wrong things.